# Python IDLE with Python 3.5.2 "crashing"

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-input, python-idle

Okay, so let me just say beforehand: I am new to Python. I was just experimenting with IDLE and then I had this weird "crash". I put "crash" inside speech marks because I'm not sure if it qualifies as a crash, as rather than the program just crashing the way a normal program would in Windows, it still runs, but whenever I press enter and try and get it to accept new text it doesn't do anything. E.g. if you try and type "print('a')" and then hit enter it just goes to the next line (and doesn't print 'a'). I tried to make a simple function which converted an integer to a string where each character in the string was either a '1' or a '0', forming the binary number representing said (unsigned) integer.

```
>>> def int_to_str(int_in):
        str_out=''
        bit_val=1<<int_in.bit_length()
        while(int_in>0):
            if(int_in>bit_val):
                str_out+='1'
                int_in-=bit_val
            else:
                str_out+='0'
            bit_val>>=1
        return str_out

>>> print('a')
print('c')
```

Basically, it becomes completely unresponsive to my input, and allows me to edit/change "print('a')" even though I shouldn't be able to if it had actually "accepted" my input. Why is this? What have I done wrong/messed up?

Also, I made sure it isn't something else I was previously messing around with by closing the shell and opening it again and only putting in said code for the "int_to_string" function, and I haven't changed any settings or imported any modules before hand or anything like that (in case it matters).

EDIT: I tried reinstalling, and that helped a bit in that I can now do other stuff fine, but the moment I try to use the "str_to_int()" function, it has this same weird behaviour of not accepting/interpreting any more user input.

Comment: Are you sure that you are in the shell and not in a code window? If it isn't that, perhaps your installation is somehow corrupt.

Comment: @JohnColeman Hahaha. Yes, I'm sure. I can provide a screenshot if you don't believe me.

Comment: I have no ideas then, if the problem persists, consider reinstalling. If you are on a Mac then there are occasionally issues involving the underlying Tk that  is behind IDLE.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because: not a programming question.

Comment: @wwii Correct me if I am mistaken, but aren't programming questions for the programming SE, and questions like these for SO? The things which are classified as on topic [from here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) are: "a specific programming problem, or a software algorithm, or software tools commonly used by programmers; and is a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development"
Maybe I am misinterpreting/misunderstanding what this means though.

Comment: @godofllamas, I could be mistaken, I'll let the community decide.  It seems off topic to me - just don't see too many IDE questions here.

Comment: The problem is not due to your function.  I cannot repeat your symptoms.

Comment: @wwii does the interpreter still work as normal after attempting to use the function?

Comment: No, you need to modify your example.  Does your while loop ever terminate?  Use some print statements and ctrl-c to break out of it.

Comment: Your posted example is misleading.

Comment: Yes, the posted example is misleading since it suggests that the interpreter allows you to enter `print('a')` *at the prompt*, after which it hangs. No such thing happens if you had previously entered  e.g. `int_to_str(42)` and gone into an infinite loop -- you would never get back to the prompt. You failed to show what you actually entered at the prompt but instead showed something which couldn't behave as you said.

Comment: @JohnColeman I didn't intend to put across that "print('a')" was causing it, I intended to show that "print('a')" wouldn't work after I had defined said function (which it didn't prior to reinstall). What would you suggest putting instead then?

Comment: How about what you actually typed (which presumably was a function call at the prompt)?  What was most misleading is that you must have (after invoking the function) typed the prompt symbol (`>>>`) yourself, while saying that the shell was doing weird things. The natural reading of your question was that it would freeze for no reason even when entering unproblematic expressions at the prompt.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it. My guess is that (after invoking the function) you copy-pasted the function definition into the shell and became confused when the shell didn't respond (not realizing that the shell was still busy with the function call). Arguably it is an odd design choice for IDLE to accept text when the shell isn't ready to process it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your while loop never terminates, you need to re-arrange your logic.  Printing variables can be an effective debugging tool - like this:

```
>>> def int_to_str(int_in):
        str_out=''
        bit_val=1<<int_in.bit_length()
        while(int_in>0):
            print(int_in, bit_val)
            if(int_in>bit_val):
                str_out+='1'
                int_in-=bit_val
            else:
                str_out+='0'
            bit_val>>=1
        return str_out
```

---

If your program seems to be going on too long you can stop it with ctrl-c.

Comment: I thought it would be something trivial. That is indeed what it was. Thanks!